# Why my program is crashing everytime when I run it?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, insertion

I'm trying to learn Insertion techniques in Linked list. During execution, it crashes everytime saying the program has stopped working. It showed no errors whatsoever. I'm new to Stack Overflow. So pardon me if this question was already asked. Here is my code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    };

    void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
    {
     struct node* new_node= (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     new_node->data=new_data;
     new_node->next=(*head_ref);
     (*head_ref)=new_node;
    }
    void insertAfter(struct node* prev_node, int new_data)
    {
    if(prev_node==NULL)
    {printf("The previous node cannot be NULL");
        return;
    }
    struct node* new_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data=new_data;
    new_node->next=prev_node->next;
    prev_node->next=new_node;

    }

    void append(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
    {
    struct node* new_node= (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *last= *head_ref;
    new_node->data=new_data;
    new_node->next=NULL;
    if(*head_ref==NULL)
    {
        *head_ref=new_node;
    }
    else
        while(last->next!=NULL)
    {
        last=last->next;  /* Segmentation fault */
    }
    last->next=new_node;
    return;
    }

      void printlist(struct node *node)
    {
      while(node!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",node->data);
        node=node->next;
    }

    }
    int main()
    {
    struct node* head=NULL;
    append(&head,6);
    push(&head,7);
    push(&head,11);
    append(&head,4);
insertAfter(head->next,12);
printf("\n Created Linked list is:");
printlist(head);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Use a debugger, narrow down the offending instruction first.

Comment: Well, now it said something about Segmentation fault. How do you fix that? (Sorry, I'm still new to programming)

Comment: Also some formatting of your code would not go amiss.

Comment: We need to know **where** the error is occurring...

Comment: Mind you also `(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` the cast is unnecessary and potentially obscures type errors.

Answer (score 2):

You check the case where the head is `NULL`, but the `else` clause contains only the `while` loop. The assignment to `last` is carried out in both cases.

You should place braces around the `else` clause:

```
    void append(struct node **head_ref, int new_data)
    {
        struct node *new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        struct node *last = *head_ref;

        new_node->data = new_data;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        if (*head_ref == NULL) {
            *head_ref = new_node;
        } else {
            while (last->next != NULL) {
                last = last->next;
            }
            last->next = new_node;
        }
    }
```

Proper indentation will make such errors stand out. In my opinion, it is also a good idea to use braces throughout, perhaps with the exception of very short `if`s without `else` in the inner loop.

Comment: Proper indentation and using braces FTW.  (and some whitespace never killed anyone)

Answer (score 0):

At least, you are trying to dereference a NULL pointer (in `append`).

You probably want `if (head_ref==NULL)` instead of `if (*head_ref==NULL)`.